# Rails objects lasting between sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, reddit

I am using the [Snoo Gem](https://github.com/paradox460/snoo) to build a Rails app for reddit.

In my `ApplicationController` I create the `Snoo` object like so:

```
  def reddit
    @reddit ||= Snoo::Client.new
  end
```

I then authorize my user in another controller. What I am now noticing though is a new `Snoo` client isnt being created every time a new user visits the app. If I access my app from an incognito browser or even another computer all together, they are still logged in to the same reddit account as was authorized.

How do I tell rails to create a new `Snoo` client for each visitor?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @creativereason Not yet. It doesnt really have anything to do with a sessions I dont think. I'm confused why rails isnt making a new Snoo object in memory for every visitor instead of reusing the same object.

Comment: Maybe dig into the Snoo Gem to see if it is a singleton? 

Another option is try logging out when you are done with that session: 
`@reddit.log_out`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: 
I know nothing about the Snoo Gem, but it sounds like it's trying to keep one connection to the API around (singleton), maybe asking on the Snoo github?

You could try resetting manually to nil or new...or logging out?

To use it in your example:

```
def reddit
    @reddit = nil #manually reset
    @reddit ||= Snoo::Client.new
end
```

or

```
def reddit
    @reddit = Snow::Client.new #always a new instance..?
end
```